# out of memory when generate cloudfoundry deploy manifest file cf-deployment.yml for openstack

Tags: deployment, memory-leaks, installation, out-of-memory, cloud-foundry

I try use follow command to generate cloud foundry deployment file cf-deployment.yml in my VM(centos7 it already installed an openstack environment, rdo juno)

```
./generate_deployment_manifest openstack cf-stub.yml > cf-deployment.yml
```

the cf-stub.yml content is in follow

```
# The following line helps maintain current documentation at http://docs.cloudfoundry.org.
# code_snippet cf-stub-openstack start
---
director_uuid:  90c73a6e-4fd1-41bb-9282-299eb49af9fc
meta:
  openstack:
    net_id: 9e5a6fd5-fa2e-48da-94ce-f85337bc2451
    auth_url: http://172.24.10.128:5000/v2.0
    tenant: demo
    username: demo
    api_key: openstack
    security_groups: [bosh]
  floating_static_ips:
  - 172.24.10.133
networks:
- name: cf1
  subnets:
    - cloud_properties:
      static:
      - 10.0.5.20 - 0.0.0.50
properties:
  cc:
    droplets:
      droplet_directory_key: cloudfoundry-droplets 
    buildpacks:
      buildpack_directory_key: cloudfoundry-buildpacks
    staging_upload_user: update
    staging_upload_password: openstack
    bulk_api_password: openstack
    db_encryption_key: openstack
  ccdb:
    roles:
    - name: ccadmin
      password: openstack
      tag: admin
  databases:
    roles:
    - name: ccadmin
      password: openstack
    - name: uaaadmin
      password: openstack
  dea_next:
    disk_mb: 2048
    memory_mb: 1024
  domain: example.com
  loggregator_endpoint:
    shared_secret: openstack
  nats:
    user: nats
    password: openstack
  router:
    enable_ssl: true
    ssl_cert: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      MIIDBjCCAe4CCQCz3nn1SWrDdTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBFMQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
      VTETMBEGA1UECBMKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UEChMYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0
      cyBQdHkgTHRkMB4XDTE1MDMwMzE4NTMyNloXDTE2MDMwMjE4NTMyNlowRTELMAkG
      A1UEBhMCQVUxEzARBgNVBAgTClNvbWUtU3RhdGUxITAfBgNVBAoTGEludGVybmV0
      IFdpZGdpdHMgUHR5IEx0ZDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEB
      AKtTK9xq/ycRO3fWbk1abunYf9CY6sl0Wlqm9UPMkI4j0itY2OyGyn1YuCCiEdM3
      b8guGSWB0XSL5PBq33e7ioiaH98UEe+Ai+TBxnJsro5WQ/TMywzRDhZ4E7gxDBav
      88ZY+y7ts0HznfxqEIn0Gu/UK+s6ajYcIy7d9L988+hA3K1FSdes8MavXhrI4xA1
      fY21gESfFkD4SsqvrkISC012pa7oVw1f94slIVcAG+l9MMAkatBGxgWAQO6kxk5o
      oH1Z5q2m0afeQBfFqzu5lCITLfgTWCUZUmbF6UpRhmD850/LqNtryAPrLLqXxdig
      OHiWqvFpCusOu/4z1uGC5xECAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAV5RAFVQy
      8Krs5c9ebYRseXO6czL9/Rfrt/weiC1XLcDkE2i2yYsBXazMYr58o4hACJwe2hoC
      bihBZ9XnVpASEYHDLwDj3zxFP/bTuKs7tLhP7wz0lo8i6k5VSPAGBq2kjc/cO9a3
      TMmLPks/Xm42MCSWGDnCEX1854B3+JK3CNEGqSY7FYXU4W9pZtHPZ3gBoy0ymSpg
      mpleiY1Tbn5I2X7vviMW7jeviB5ivkZaXtObjyM3vtPLB+ILpa15ZhDSE5o71sjA
      jXqrE1n5o/GXHX+1M8v3aJc30Az7QAqWohW/tw5SoiSmVQZWd7gFht9vSzaH2WgO
      LwcpBC7+cUJEww==
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    ssl_key: |
      -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
      MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAq1Mr3Gr/JxE7d9ZuTVpu6dh/0JjqyXRaWqb1Q8yQjiPSK1jY
      7IbKfVi4IKIR0zdvyC4ZJYHRdIvk8Grfd7uKiJof3xQR74CL5MHGcmyujlZD9MzL
      DNEOFngTuDEMFq/zxlj7Lu2zQfOd/GoQifQa79Qr6zpqNhwjLt30v3zz6EDcrUVJ
      16zwxq9eGsjjEDV9jbWARJ8WQPhKyq+uQhILTXalruhXDV/3iyUhVwAb6X0wwCRq
      0EbGBYBA7qTGTmigfVnmrabRp95AF8WrO7mUIhMt+BNYJRlSZsXpSlGGYPznT8uo
      22vIA+ssupfF2KA4eJaq8WkK6w67/jPW4YLnEQIDAQABAoIBAQCDVqpcOoZKK9K8
      Bt3eXQKEMJ2ji2cKczFFJ5MEm9EBtoJLCryZbqfSue3Fzpj9pBUEkBpk/4VT5F7o
      0/Vmc5Y7LHRcbqVlRtV30/lPBPQ4V/eWtly/AZDcNsdfP/J1fgPSvaoqCr2ORLWL
      qL/vEfyIeM4GcWy0+JMcPbmABslw9O6Ptc5RGiP98vCLHQh/++sOtj6PH1pt+2X/
      Uecv3b1Hk/3Oe+M8ySorJD3KA94QTRnKX+zubkxRg/zCAki+as8rQc/d+BfVG698
      ylUT5LVLNuwbWnffY2Zt5x5CDqH01mJnHmxzQEfn68rb3bGFaYPEn9EP+maQijv6
      SsUM9A3lAoGBAODRDRn4gEIxjPICp6aawRrMDlRc+k6IWDF7wudjxJlaxFr2t7FF
      rFYm+jrcG6qMTyq+teR8uHpcKm9X8ax0L6N6gw5rVzIeIOGma/ZuYIYXX2XJx5SW
      SOas1xW6qEIbOMv+Xu9w2SWbhTgyRmtlxxjr2e7gQLz9z/vuTReJpInnAoGBAMMW
      sq5lqUfAQzqxlhTobQ7tnB48rUQvkGPE92SlDj2TUt9phek2/TgRJT6mdcozvimt
      JPhxKg3ioxG8NPmN0EytjpSiKqlxS1R2po0fb75vputfpw16Z8/2Vik+xYqNMTLo
      SpeVkHu7fbtNYEK2qcU44OyOZ/V+5Oo9TuBIFRhHAoGACkqHhwDRHjaWdR2Z/w5m
      eIuOvF3lN2MWZm175ouynDKDeoaAsiS2VttB6R/aRFxX42UHfoYXC8LcTmyAK5zF
      8X3SMf7H5wtqBepQVt+Gm5zGSSqLcEnQ3H5c+impOh105CGoxt0rk4Ui/AeRIalv
      C70AJOcvD3eu5aFq9gDe/1ECgYBAhkVbASzYGnMh+pKVH7rScSxto8v6/XBYT1Ez
      7JOlMhD667/qvtFJtgIHkq7qzepbhnTv5x3tscQVnZY34/u9ILpD1s8dc+dibEvx
      6S/gYLVorB5ois/DLMqaobRcew6Gs+XX9RPwmLahOJpZ9mh4XrOmCgPAYtP71YM9
      ExpHCQKBgQCMMDDWGMRdFMJgXbx1uMere7OoniBdZaOexjbglRh1rMVSXqzBoU8+
      yhEuHGAsHGWQdSBHnqRe9O0Bj/Vlw2VVEaJeL1ewRHb+jXSnuKclZOJgMsJAvgGm
      SOWIahDrATA4g1T6yLBWQPhj3ZXD3eCMxT1Q3DvpG1DjgvXwmXQJAA==
      -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    cipher_suites: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    status:
      user: router_user
      password: openstack
    secure_cookies: true
  uaa:
    admin:
      client_secret: openstack
    batch:
      username: batch
      password: openstack
    cc:
      client_secret: openstack
    clients:
      app-direct:
        secret: openstack
      developer_console:
        secret: openstack
      notifications:
        secret: openstack
      login:
        secret: openstack
      doppler:
        secret: openstack
      cloud_controller_username_lookup:
        secret: cloud_controller_username_lookup_secret
      gorouter:
        secret: openstack
    jwt:
      verification_key: 
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAw6WKxiVxx5+rqoMvj4vk
        X5FpipdWaVLpcPhmN8O5ut2bqcU8KV6pMV7/n+zowITVFHCbS/6J6Uk875NclTC1
        UI86Pxn3c+14KYL6KLe/Gi8McRyqvO5BpkQr3BTtBe9Z0EMgoeq5fAol2Lc/8SNz
        /uLdSkMc5CmtpEgZ7isnsc8ExSDCchRmrCmKaxIPxNUZvCYgqqXXduHBln1/MBJV
        YjsEXZZSbhLWzVaFOdAKkU9DlWxqI6sRWFSl6qZ3JCuMh3MQqLnFFXPAX8C9hxFV
        oC2i7Fe6AIFyECJijgfieqi0PiBdMZ29Kj36gssktVhE+5TAcGCdFqdfzXOBC2ih
        /wIDAQAB
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
      signing_key: 
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAw6WKxiVxx5+rqoMvj4vkX5FpipdWaVLpcPhmN8O5ut2bqcU8
        KV6pMV7/n+zowITVFHCbS/6J6Uk875NclTC1UI86Pxn3c+14KYL6KLe/Gi8McRyq
        vO5BpkQr3BTtBe9Z0EMgoeq5fAol2Lc/8SNz/uLdSkMc5CmtpEgZ7isnsc8ExSDC
        chRmrCmKaxIPxNUZvCYgqqXXduHBln1/MBJVYjsEXZZSbhLWzVaFOdAKkU9DlWxq
        I6sRWFSl6qZ3JCuMh3MQqLnFFXPAX8C9hxFVoC2i7Fe6AIFyECJijgfieqi0PiBd
        MZ29Kj36gssktVhE+5TAcGCdFqdfzXOBC2ih/wIDAQABAoIBAFHF3zrya5wEILwk
        GLzmu402OeazWmqrPOb6675jED4KYgWTapHf/tej3TP60U2mN2lTp5UbzoizE8UO
        0qOIuD/znWTCdar+ljrDg8uBAV7wS0L7uGE/NDFKTQqvtGHGqMNjS0Bh2yT9GNR7
        wz4Gk3T1XYishGbZBLqlaDEj2HN4V1Yy1Qp4KohqLsJN4B5+c2Q0HrTejOHeSsou
        B7nJndfZm2ljKdoql++4UZPjWGLGSdtLhzLvYkzbql0GYBYVTOmn/A7AZLz2w769
        RmDt28nqOIXIAqDL6qt/frtDfCknbsk7lSEFDlrRfjjPIuah/1UCo80Kjd3Iv+rb
        4NZxiAECgYEA+X1WCCWIWP4hlSjRtISpjOaStz8d5eDLeSTI14cPYM7cMiyROrEo
        SCJm10AYIs5TsBlb5AfQlBV2YrcmdxeG4ARlVOnpki3ZAyQlQi5LQenQh9abqKtY
        b2Z0udDmPgwgtPYexdh1FQTzeXptYDED/sHynj6pN4GBIlZTjZXiCwsCgYEAyMCE
        8MEPJZmAQ8vaWjzkzbToUbW5knrEhRNEoxnlbRXXwzXReUIbu+E22FQjwNNxlsJx
        smKFWzPvF5seiChBp7yT9dnDKCm9bJVRRAlVD5oyBIFkqXmCn3QM9ySWW6QHxgEH
        4wsoNs0RcpTNW/CLi7E9tvtzjnoFqdfDIaSbPV0CgYBhv56OcI4cN+1WcHjBHl0D
        rG79RshjAZEW9LeP4gW/ayzQp6967GAY6wmZ+i26rVYSn8zl6b3p1wLcKF/0tw4M
        BQzimQb/U+E7ntTOOi8YMxCVuBqimgd7FgxTpSogU0YZQHjMEUPGKXtvM+1Yi7vB
        +6EgKPLJoX7DwkjYJ0o6AwKBgQC842gyn3SBDE2DfOuWvHUMmIt/Vl2lVZ5TGC4c
        yOD2IvdA1gKi9XDi9qWEJqb9Z/YYxBv2nHyds9/jdjDkK/yatvUA/kSCJcP1xwkP
        2zgN1if51UXBsHMXVTpd0C8pSs2FoLKrDnRoG8uu5BPVzh9+8OYApde011s806bm
        oNrwgQKBgQCW/CUPXOrfyIwdFIEqSPB79GuV9e27cm8iB8Fu+Rcc3xlQc+3Ak97X
        bLi2C1to/pMX+q8ksudd1jOMoyhufle8wJaxC0jLgVx4DGUorvA0uiVtEAULreXz
        beE4LXyvVu+tYIl4ATlIyEQSAnNIR6oCX5KvQJu+jHA4i9z+Vg0mpA==
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    scim:
      users:
      - admin|openstack|scim.write,scim.read,openid,cloud_controller.admin,doppler.firehose
  uaadb:
    roles:
    - name: uaaadmin
      password: openstack
      tag: admin

# code_snippet cf-stub-openstack end
# The previous line helps maintain current documentation at http://docs.cloudfoundry.org.
```

then I get the **error**

```
./generate_deployment_manifest openstack cf-stub.yml > cf-deployment.yml
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.SysMap(0xc3d3860000, 0x72eb0000, 0x754900, 0x75ca58)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mem_linux.c:149 +0x98
runtime.MHeap_SysAlloc(0x762140, 0x72eb0000, 0x429d02)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.c:284 +0x124
runtime.MHeap_Alloc(0x762140, 0x39755, 0x10100000000, 0xc208000120)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.c:240 +0x66

goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.switchtoM()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:198 fp=0xc208141858 sp=0xc208141850
runtime.mallocgc(0x72ea9ff0, 0x61e9e0, 0x0, 0x73c280)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:199 +0x9f3 fp=0xc208141908 sp=0xc208141858
runtime.newarray(0x61e9e0, 0x4c9c6aa, 0x57be3e)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:365 +0xc1 fp=0xc208141940 sp=0xc208141908
runtime.growslice(0x5946c0, 0xc377970000, 0x3d49eaa, 0x3d49eaa, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/slice.go:87 +0x2bb fp=0xc2081419a0 sp=0xc208141940
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml.ipRange(0xc208156cd0, 0x10, 0x10, 0xc208156d20, 0x10, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml/call.go:187 +0x221 fp=0xc208141a58 sp=0xc2081419a0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml.staticIPPool(0xc208156c90, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc208141be0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml/call.go:173 +0x296 fp=0xc208141b88 sp=0xc208141a58
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml.generateStaticIPs(0x7f63bde43170, 0xc208046370, 0xc2081564c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x600000000000000)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml/call.go:63 +0x16f fp=0xc208141ca0 sp=0xc208141b88
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml.CallExpr.Evaluate(0xc208156211, 0xa, 0xc2081560b0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x7f63bde43170, 0xc208046370, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc208141e00)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml/call.go:33 +0x2bc fp=0xc208141d88 sp=0xc208141ca0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/dynaml.(*CallExpr).Evaluate(0xc20810c9f0, 0x7f63bde43170, 0xc208046370, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc208046370)
    <autogenerated>:11 +0xc6 fp=0xc208141de0 sp=0xc208141d88
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b85c0, 0xc208208060, 0x3, 0x4, 0xc20800a500, 0x5, 0x8, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:49 +0x2df fp=0xc208141f08 sp=0xc208141de0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flowMap(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b8600, 0xc208208060, 0x3, 0x4, 0xc208034600, 0x4, 0x6, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:98 +0x8c7 fp=0xc208142278 sp=0xc208141f08
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b8600, 0xc208156b10, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc208034600, 0x4, 0x6, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:43 +0x131 fp=0xc2081423a0 sp=0xc208142278
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flowList(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b8660, 0xc208156b10, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc208145580, 0x3, 0x4, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:113 +0x420 fp=0xc208142600 sp=0xc2081423a0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b8660, 0xc208156b10, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc208145580, 0x3, 0x4, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:46 +0x1ed fp=0xc208142728 sp=0xc208142600
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flowMap(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b87e0, 0xc208156b10, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc208149ea0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:98 +0x8c7 fp=0xc208142a98 sp=0xc208142728
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc2080b87e0, 0xc2080440c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc208149ea0, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:43 +0x131 fp=0xc208142bc0 sp=0xc208142a98
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flowList(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc208148fc0, 0xc2080440c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc208156a70, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:113 +0x420 fp=0xc208142e20 sp=0xc208142bc0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc208148fc0, 0xc2080440c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc208156a70, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:46 +0x1ed fp=0xc208142f48 sp=0xc208142e20
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flowMap(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc208149b80, 0xc2080440c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:98 +0x8c7 fp=0xc2081432b8 sp=0xc208142f48
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc208149b80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:43 +0x131 fp=0xc2081433e0 sp=0xc2081432b8
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.Flow(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc20801f2c0, 0xc20800a340, 0x1, 0x4, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/flow.go:19 +0xd6 fp=0xc208143500 sp=0xc2081433e0
github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow.Cascade(0x7f63bde41ef0, 0xc208073960, 0xc20800a300, 0x5, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/flow/cascade.go:9 +0x100 fp=0xc208143590 sp=0xc208143500
main.merge(0x7fffddc9a701, 0x1d, 0xc20800a030, 0x5, 0x5)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/spiff.go:90 +0xd0c fp=0xc208143770 sp=0xc208143590
main.func·001(0xc20807a1c0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/spiff.go:36 +0x124 fp=0xc2081437e8 sp=0xc208143770
github.com/codegangsta/cli.Command.Run(0x63a750, 0x5, 0x63a510, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x67e3f0, 0x29, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli/command.go:118 +0x104b fp=0xc208143be8 sp=0xc2081437e8
github.com/codegangsta/cli.(*App).Run(0xc20806c0f0, 0xc20800a000, 0x8, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/codegangsta/cli/app.go:177 +0xdf6 fp=0xc208143ee8 sp=0xc208143be8
main.main()
    /Users/fraenkel/go/src/github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/spiff/spiff.go:60 +0x292 fp=0xc208143f98 sp=0xc208143ee8
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:63 +0xf3 fp=0xc208143fe0 sp=0xc208143f98
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.4.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2232 +0x1 fp=0xc208143fe8 sp=0xc208143fe0
```

even I config my vm to 10g ram, the error still there, this let me start to think it may be not a memory issue. so I ask here.

does any body can give me some advice ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: can any body give me some sugguestion?

Answer (score 0):

this error cause by the  - 10.0.5.20 - 0.0.0.50 ip error, if the ip is not in same net xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx- xxx.xxx.yyy.xxx will cause OOM error